# Cannot use SciPy's non-linear least square with function containing sum

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, least-squares, minimization

So I am trying to use the leastsq function from scipy.optimize for a minimization problem.
I keep getting the following error and cannot understand why:

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "lesatsq_viscoelast.py", line 161, in <module>
viscoelas_parameters()
File "devoir04.py", line 117, in exercice02
plsq = leastsq( residuals, betas, args = ( deformation_dagger, time ) )
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 283, in leastsq
gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
minpack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

I thought, after online researches that the problem was that I was not giving an array as initial values to leastsq but it does not solve my problem...

Here is my simplified code:

```
from numpy import *
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

time = []
deformation = []
time, deformation = import_data_04_02( "data.csv" )
time = asarray( time )
deformation = asarray( deformation )

#initial vector
betas = []
for i in range(0, 12):
    betas.append( 0. )
betas = asarray(betas)

plsq = leastsq( residuals, betas, args = ( deformation, time ) )


def residuals( x, deformation, time ):
    err = []
    for i in range(0, len(time)):
        err.append( deformation - deformation_theory( time[i], x ) )
    return asarray( err )

#The function that should fit the set of data I have, with x a vector I am trying to determine
def deformation_theory( time, x ):

    lambdas = []
    for i in range(0, 50, 5):
        lambdas.append( 1./pow(10, float(i)/10.)  )

    stress = 20.

    for i in range(0, len(lambdas)):
        if i == 0:
            f = x[0]
        else:
            f = f + x[i] * (1. - exp( -lambdas[i-1]* time  ) )
    f = f * stress
    return f
```

My goal is to find the best set of `betas[i]` (called `x` in the theoretical function) values, using a set of data I measured from experiments (deformation through time) so that the residual is minimal, which will mean that I have the best set of beta value.